# List of checkboxes in a contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I want to create a simple wysiwyg and I want one of the options is to add a list of checkboxes, much like a an unordered list, but having checkboxes at the beginning of each element.

My main idea is to use **javascript document.execCommand** to edit the WYSIWYG box with a contentEditable div, much like this one: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand/

But when I create a button for a checkboxlist, I still have no idea on how can I create one with the same behavior as a ul, generating new ones by pressing enter and stopping on double enter. Any ideas?

Comment: I am sure you will not remember this thing anymore but still asking have you found any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work LIKE what you are asking for, although it may need to be edited to reflect what you really want to do with your list of checkboxes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>test-page</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
//<!--

var bxs, clk, dv, lng, tx, spn, und;

function newone()
{ if(bxs == und)  //if undefined do initialization stuff once
  { bxs = [];    //array of checkboxes, accessible any time
    clk = document.getElementById("clk");    //"click" message
    dv = document.getElementById("addmore"); //"div" element
    tx = document.getElementById("txbx");    //"textbox" element
  }
  lng = bxs.length;                 //current number of checkboxes
  spn = document.createElement("span") //create a "span" element
  spn.innerHTML = "&nbsp; &nbsp;";     //indent from left of page
  bxs[lng] = document.createElement("input"); //create checkbox
  bxs[lng].type = "checkbox";
  spn.appendChild(bxs[lng]); //put it inside the "span" element
  dv.insertBefore(spn, tx); //put the "span" element inside the "div"
  tx.value = "";            //ensure textbox has no text
  tx.hidden = false;        //display the textbox
  clk.hidden = true;       //hide the "click" message
  tx.focus();              //let user start typing in the textbox
  return;
}

function tstkey(e)
{ if((e.keyCode == 13) &&     //Enter key pressed?
     (tx.value.length > 2)) //check minimum entry length
  { spn.innerHTML += (tx.value + "<br />"); //finish current line
    newone();  //create another checkbox
  }
  else if((e.keyCode == 27) || //Escape pressed?
          ((e.keyCode == 13) &&       //or
           (tx.value.length == 0))) //blank entry?
  { dv.removeChild(spn);  //remove last-added "span"
    bxs.length = lng; //remove last-added checkbox
    tx.hidden = true; //hide the textbox
    clk.hidden = false; //display the "click" message
  }
  return;
}

 // -->
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="addmore">
<input id="txbx" type="text" size="30" maxlength="50" hidden="hidden" onkeydown="tstkey(event);" /><br />
<span id="clk" onclick="newone();" style="background-color:#C0C0C0;">click to create a new checkbox item</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```